# Solving a system of linear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For $-\infty<x<\infty$, $t>0$,
\begin{cases}
u_t-v_x=0,\\
v_t-u_x=0,\\
u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2},\\
v(x,0)=0.
\end{cases}

I would like to know the approach to solve this system of equations. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation allows to separate into two independant EDP of the Laplace kind :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We take Laplace transforms in time $(t)$, and Fourier transforms in space $(x)$.  Taking the Fourier  transform of the first two equations we get

\begin{align*}
0&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}U(\omega,t) + i \omega V(\omega, t)\\
0&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} V(\omega,t) + i \omega  V(\omega,t)
\end{align*}

Now we take the Laplace transform and get

\begin{align*}
0&=s\mathcal{U}(\omega, s) - U(\omega,0)+ i\omega \mathcal{V}(\omega, s)\\
0&=s \mathcal{V}(\omega,s) -V(\omega,0)+ i\omega \mathcal{U}(\omega, s)
\end{align*}

Now, by taking the fourier transform (in space) of the initial conditions we learn that  $U(\omega,0) = \exp(-|\omega|)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} $ and $V(\omega,0) = 0$.  Plugging in these transformed initial conditions we get

\begin{align*}
0 &= s\mathcal{U}(\omega,s) - \exp(-|\omega|) + i \omega \mathcal{V}(\omega,s)\\
0 &= s\mathcal{V}(\omega,s) + i\omega \mathcal{U}(\omega,s)
\end{align*}
Solve the second equation for $\mathcal{V}(\omega,s_)$ and plug it into the first equation, we get

\begin{align*}0= s\mathcal{U}(\omega,s) -\exp(-|\omega|) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } + \frac{\omega^2}{s} \mathcal{U}(\omega,s)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow (s^2+\omega^2)\mathcal{U}(\omega,s) = s \exp(-|\omega|) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow \mathcal{U}(\omega,s) =\frac{ s}{s^2+\omega^2}  \exp(-|\omega|) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align*}

Now we take the inverse laplace transform and get

$U(\omega, t) = \cos(\omega t) \exp(-|\omega|) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Now we can take the inverse Fourier transform and get

\begin{align*}
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-(x-t)^2} + \frac{1}{1-(x+t)^2}\right).
\end{align*}

Now, we can recover $v(x,t)$ by using similar techniques and obtain

\begin{align*}
v(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+(x+t)^2} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2}.
\end{align*}